# Thought for Magento 1 ongoing support

Tags: discussion, support, suggestion

Magento team decided that they will postpone the support for Magento 1 ([source](https://magento.com/blog/magento-news/ongoing-magento-1-support)) , Is there any specific reason behind this ? Because previously they Informed that they will end support for Magento 1 at 17 November 2018(@benmarks at at #mm17cz) .

Still Magento team not sure about Magento 2 ?  And for new projects should we continue with Magento 2 or Magento 1 ? Any thoughts for this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I always prefer M2 over M1 for new projects.

Because we all know in near future Magento will stop its support for M1, right now its just postponed. So may be in 2019 or after that, they might stop their support for Magento 1.

So for my point of view M2 is future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Murtuza, I do agree with you. But after this decision from Magento I am scratching my head :)